# Use existing user accounts of an existing website

Tags: database, authentication, single-sign-on, basic-authentication

I have a website named satellite.com built by AngularJS+NodeJS+MongoDB, it has an authentication system by ID & password, or third-parties like Google, GitHub. It already has many user accounts.

Now, I want to build a new website named umbrella.com, its authentication system and its database by ReactJS+NodeJS+MongoDB. Umbrella.com will include the functionalities of satellite.com (which will ideally share code with satellite.com) and some other functionalities. In the future, I want both satellite.com and umbrella.com to exist and work (though satellite.com may systematically redirect to umbrella.com/satellite/).

I wonder how umbrella.com can use the existing user accounts of satellite.com. Ideally, I hope

1. existing users of satellite.com could sign in umbrella.com with their old credentials, and have access to their data of satellite.com
2. new users could sign up on satellite.com, which will be valid to umbrella.com too
3. new users could sign up on umbrella.com, which will be valid to satellite.com too

I have total control of the two websites. Does anyone have a clear suggestion on how to structure and share the authentication system and the database of these 2 websites?

**Edit 1:** one issue is that when I set up Google Authentication for satellite.com, I remember that the domain name (i.e., satellite.com) was required. So now, can we use these authentications for another domain name (i.e., umbrella.com)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using third party authentication like Google Auth or something where you have to specifically register your domain you can achieve that by following steps:

- You can keep one database structure for both website with different
  front-end. For that you user can login to both websites using same
  credentials.
- You can also go with one backend (Node server) for both the websites
  as its seems like both are same and having same functionality.
  Front-end can be different.

Comment: one issue is that when I set up Google Authentication for satellite.com, I remember that the domain name (i.e., satellite.com) was required. So now, can we use these authentications for another domain name (i.e., umbrella.com)?

Comment: In that case this is not possible. Google Authentication not allow single client Id for multiple site. I have found the question asked before for using same ClientID for multiple site. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677864/google-oauth-client-id-for-multiple-site-multitalency-purpose)